# Receiving following error "SELECT STATEMENTS INCLUDED WITHIN A FUNCTION CANNOT RETURN DATA TO A CLIENT"

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

I am trying to create the following function:

```
Create function mastercount
(
    @table nvarchar(50)
    , @policy nvarchar(20)
    , @firstname nvarchar(20)
    , @lastname nvarchar (20)
)    
Returns nvarchar (50)
As
Begin
    Declare @count int =''

    If @table ='A'
        Select count (*)
        from A
        where policy = @policy and firstname = @firstname and lastname = @lastname    
    Else If @table ='B'
        Select count (*)
        from A
        where policy = @policy and firstname = @firstname and lastname = @lastname    
    Else If @table ='A'
        Select count (*)
        from A
        where policy = @policy and firstname = @firstname and lastname = @lastname

    Return @count;
End
```

But am receiving an error:

> SELECT STATEMENTS INCLUDED WITHIN A FUNCTION CANNOT RETURN DATA TO A CLIENT

Comment: Yep, you can't do that in a function. As the error message clearly states. What is your question? Probably you want to assign to `@count` instead of straight `select`

Comment: Your path likely stems from schema issues and will likely lead you to a dead-end. Since your function appears to be generating a count of rows, the return type should be int or bigint, not nvarchar.

Comment: My question is how can I return a count without getting this error, can anyone please elaborate it?

Comment: Martin has already told you e.g. [select into variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/select-local-variable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: And get your datatypes right, @Count should be assigned 0 not an empty string. The function should be set to return a 'int' not a varchar.

Comment: Perhaps writing `Select @count  =  count (*)`?

Comment: Better yet, don't use SELECT to assign a scalar value. Use SET. Example: `set @count = (select count(*) from ....);` Notice the statement terminator - start developing good habits.

Comment: @SMor why is `set @Count = (select ...)` better than `select @Count = count(*) ...`?

Comment: In this case not much difference IMO. `SET` will throw an error if multiple rows returned and coerce zero rows to `NULL` but not applicable here with a scalar aggregate as guaranteed one row. `SELECT` is more convenient if assigning multiple variables but again not relevant here.

Comment: And nobody's commented yet on the logic bug where "If table = 'A' ... else if table = 'A'"? that latter else if will never be executed. Also the second one, "If table = 'B' select * from A" ... shouldn't that be "select * from B"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try it this way.  The variable @count was being assigned an empty string.  I changed that to default the value to 0.  Also, the SELECT statements were attempting to return records to the client.  Now they are each assigned to the variable @count instead.

```
Create function mastercount
(
    @table nvarchar(50)
    , @policy nvarchar(20)
    , @firstname nvarchar(20)
    , @lastname nvarchar (20)
)    
Returns int
As
Begin
    Declare @count int=0;

    If @table ='A'
        Select @count=count(*)
        from A
        where policy = @policy and firstname = @firstname and lastname = @lastname    
    Else If @table ='B'
        Select @count=count(*)
        from A
        where policy = @policy and firstname = @firstname and lastname = @lastname    
    Else If @table ='A'
        Select @count=count(*)
        from A
        where policy = @policy and firstname = @firstname and lastname = @lastname

    Return @count;
End
```